# ́╗┐' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: batch, encoding, psexec

When executing certain files (mainly batch) using PsExec I get these weird ́╗┐' symbols before my command.
My initial thought was, that I were using wrong encoding, but after checking, I realized that all my files were using UTF-8.

Comment: Why not convert them to UTF-16LE instead?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is that Windows doesn't usually use UTF-8.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I get these weird ́╗┐' symbols before my command […] all my files were using UTF-8.

This has two causes:

1. *cmd.exe* does not support UTF-8. It always uses one of the single-byte encodings often called "OEM" – cp437, cp775, and so on, depending on the system's regional settings.

   (I expected it to support UTF-16 as well, but apparently not; not even if I added the UTF-16 BOM.)
2. Your text editor is adding an UTF-8 "byte order mark" (bytes `EF` `BB` `BF`) to the beginning of all UTF-8 files.

   When *cmd.exe* reads your script, it doesn't know what to do with the mark – it sees the BOM as three ordinary cp437 characters, `’` `╗` `┐`, and attempts to use them as part of the command name.

Configure your editor to stop adding the BOM to UTF-8–encoded files. (It only makes sense in UTF-16, and is *very* useless in UTF-8.)

> Would compiling the batch files into an exe solve the issue?

uh

what

Comment: I wouldn't say BOMs are "very useless" in UTF-8; though they are in this particular case. Many applications use them to determine the text actually is UTF-8 and not another encoding.

Comment: You can compile batch files to exe using a built in windows command called iexpress.exe (https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)

Answer (score 29):

To further [@dsolimano's answer](https://superuser.com/a/601294/282914), if you are *specifically* using **Visual Studio**, and in my case it's **2013**, I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Open **Visual Studio**.
2. Click **Tools** > **Options**.
3. Click **Text Editor** > **File Extension**.
4. In the **Extension** box, enter **bat**.
5. In the **Editor** drop down, select **Source Code (Text) Editor With Encoding** and click **Add**.
6. Click **OK** to save and exit.

---

Now, when you open a **.bat** file from within **Visual Studio**, you will initially get prompted with:

[image]

You will want to drill down through the options until you come to the **DOS** option of your language:

[image]

Click **OK** to finish opening the file.

---

*Ok, even though it should be fairly obvious at this point, if you can see the **`∩╗┐`** characters at the beginning of your file, it would behoove you to remove them and save the file, now with the correct encoding.  This is what prevents you from being prompted again next time.*

---

With all of that in place, you will be glad to know that you may now **view**, **edit**, and **save** your **.bat** file(s) from within **Visual Studio** so that **cmd.exe** no longer gives you the aforementioned heinous error of:

> **'∩╗┐'** is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This fix works in VS2017 perfectly too

Comment: I never would have guessed this. Still a valid solution for VS2019.

Comment: Makes perfect sense that Microsoft's premier developer tool wouldn't be configured out-of-the-box for editing Microsoft's cmd scripts.

Answer (score 12):

Those are Unicode [Byte Order Marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  Cmd.exe doesn't understand them.  If you resave your files in Notepad with ANSI encoding, that should fix the problem.

For example, I created this batch file:

```
echo Hello World
```

First I save it with UTF-8 encoding

```
C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>test.bat

C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>∩╗┐echo Hello World
'∩╗┐echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then with Unicode

```
C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>test.bat

C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>■e
'■e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

And finally with ANSI

```
C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>test.bat

C:\Users\DSolimano\Desktop\junk>echo Hello World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 6):

As explained earlier, this character is the unicode character BOM (Byte Order Mark) used as a signature and that cmd.exe does not recognize.

You can delete it safely in many ways.

I've found very easy to do as follows:

1. open the file in *Notepad++*
2. go to *Encoding menu*
3. tick the option: **Encode in UTF-8 without BOM**
4. Save, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij:
In the right bottom corner click `UTF-8` -> `Remove BOM`
[image: screenshot]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution in Windows 10.

Create New.txt file with right click command in file explorer window.

Rename it to New.bat (now it is just data format, not text format for Notepad).

Just open and edit it with Notepad.exe. Now it is UTF-8 format without BOM.

Comment: What does BOM mean?

Comment: Byte Order Marks 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark