# How do you make an bat file that talks to a server?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Basically I have employees and I don't want them to know my powershell commands.  So I would like to make my .BAT files into EXE files and everytime it is ran it will ask for a user name and password and send to the server a +1 that it was used to that account.

I know php, but wasn't sure how to do this a standalone exe file for each of my scripts?

Comment: try this out:  http://www.battoexeconverter.com/   never used it, but I found it with a simple google search

Comment: See if it helps http://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use one of the solutions in this [related post](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe) to convert your BAT file to an EXE.
2. You can write a simple single page web api that increments a counter when it is hit. You can be as creative as you want in adding validation / protection here.
3. The bat file could `curl` and hit that URL.

None of this is foolproof. The converted exe can still be reverse engineered (what is it that you need to protect)? Fake messages could be sent to your server. You may have to add checks to quit the execution if the connection fails. The user's systems may not have identical environments and cause your executable to fail. Basically, I'm answering your question, but suggesting that you have an [XY problem](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6271/user-asks-for-answer-that-wont-solve-their-problem/6273#6273) and this question is not related to your real problem.