# How can I force VSCode to start with a specific argument, from my command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know I could probably set up an alias or such, but I'm really looking for a way to ensure that VSCode will always start using a specific parameter, regardless of how it was invoked. *Without* having to set up alias, modify shortcuts, and in general try and solve this problem in a hundred different places.

I need this because VSCode, despite reporting fixes to the contrary, fails to select a proper palette when executed on a HDR enabled display.

It looks "dim".

[image]

Now I know how to make it look ok. If I start it as `code --force-color-profile srgb`, everything clears up and it looks like this.

[image]

Much better.

But I don't want to have to type this every time. And an alias would not help, when code is being executed from an external tool.

Is there a way to force this setting into VSCode in any and all instances?

Answer (score 2):

This is an (untested) hack, but can easily be undone:

- Create a batch file (`.bat`) that contains the command

  ```
  start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --force-color-profile srgb
  ```

  (The path to `code.exe` might be different on your computer.)
- Convert the file to an `.exe` called `code.exe`. See
  [How can I convert a Windows batch script to a .exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)
- In the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code`, rename `code.exe` and
  replace it by the above created file.

This might need to be repeated when/if you update Code to a new version.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** The procedure requires to change an very integral file in VSCode
installation. Editing this file with wrong JavaScript code may break it.
**Backup** the required file before doing any change further.

This procedure will apply on every Electron framework based applications.
Because the `--force-color-profile` command line option is for Chromium.
According to the [docs](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/display/display_switches.cc):

Force all monitors to be treated as though they have the specified color profile.
Accepted values are "srgb" and "generic-rgb" (currently used by Mac layout tests)
and "color-spin-gamma24" (used by layout tests).

First close any running Visual Studio Code session. Open VSCode installation folder.
Then go to resources > app > out folder. Open `main.js` file in any editor.
Add this line:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force-color-profile', 'srgb');
```

This will append the command line to underlying Chromium engine. Now open VScode.

**Source:** [Microsoft/Vscode: issue #65816](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/65816)

### Further readings:

- [Chromium Source: display_switches.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/display/display_switches.cc)
- [ElectronJS Docs: app.commandLine.appendSwitch](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appcommandlineappendswitchswitch-value)