# Universal Command-Line Tool Wrapper

Tags: windows, command-line, ghostscript, parameters

I have a program that calls GhostScript in the background by issuing a shell command with hardcoded(!) parameters. Unfortunately it is impossible to change that in a defined matter and the used parameters produce a bad result. I do have the possibility to define the path and exe of the conversion program, which gives rise to hope.

I now look for a tool that lets me fake the gswin64c.exe (or perhaps any other command line tool) but where I can provide my own set of parameters while keeping some original values like the filename(s).

I think of some "universal command line wrapper" that I can give an arbitrary name for the exe (no batch!) and maybe a defined config file that contains the necessary parameter manipulation and final call to the target program.

I have not been able to locate such a ready made tool, but I may have missed the right keywords to search for. If there is no such tool, I have to build one for myself but I don't want to invent the wheel a second time.

Comment: Honestly I suspect making a custom tool in e.g. standard C# would take _less_ effort than trying to configure a generic tool with its own made-up rule syntax, even if such a tool existed...

Answer (score 0):

You may include any command or commands with parameters inside a `.bat` file.

If the invoked program must be called `gswin64c.exe`, you may convert the `.bat`
script to an `.exe`.

See the post
[How can I convert a Windows batch script to a .exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)