# How to make a program load a rainmeter skin? (Looking for anything but a compiled AHK script)

Tags: windows-10, rainmeter

That's basically it, I'm using NTX's Scout and Lock Screen as a replacement for Launchy and win10's lock screen, and I want to be able to load it from running a program. **I don't want to write an AHK script.** The directories get weird with multiple .ini skin files when I try to use AHK. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this work? https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?t=20890#p111427 Using a Windows shortcut instead of AHK

Comment: It would work, but I'm using this dock:

https://www.deviantart.com/not-finch/art/Interactive-Dock-for-Rainmeter-772713805

and it only allows me to launch .exe files from it, not other skins or shortcuts. I'll look around in the skin's code and see if there's a way I can set it up to launch a skin if I cant somehow compile that skin into a program somehow.

Comment: Perhaps you could put the code in a batch file and see if that works. If not, convert batch to exe: https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe

Comment: ok, so i was about to try your idea and found that the ExitApp command for AHK exists so i've decided to go with the following AHK script:

```Run, C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !ToggleConfig "NXT-OS\Scout" "Scout.ini"
ExitApp```

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up using AHK and made

```
Run,
C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe !ToggleConfig "NXT-OS\Scout" "Scout.ini"
ExitApp
```

but if anyone sees this and dosen't want to use AHK but use a shortcut, you can make a shortcut to the skin itself with the directory looking like this:

```
"$drive:\$folder\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe" !ToggleConfig "$skinpath" "$skin.ini"
```