# Created a small batch file that runs in cmd prompt, unsure how to turn it into a shareable exe so I can give it to friends

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, cmd.exe

I’m such a noob at this but basically I created a small internet “cleanser” batch file for friends and family to just have a single click button to run a simple script to fix some common internet issues.

It basically is

```
ipconfig /release 
ipconfig /flushdns 
ipconfig /renew
```

Prompts if ok with a reset to continue, yes continues no doesn’t continue next two steps.

```
netsh int ip reset 
netsh winsock reset
```

200 second timer before reset of computer

My problem lies in that I can’t send batch files over their emails or usb drive because it gets flags as possibly harmful. The other point is that I have to give me instructions to run it.   It has been very helpful and I felt proud for making it.

I was looking how to make small interface and exe to where it could run these things and make it easier for them.

It won’t be flagged and I can have it just a button press for the user and it tells them exactly what the program is doing.

I am just getting started.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert a Windows batch script to a .exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)

Comment: You can take a look directly to this link [Converting .bat to .exe with no additional external software (Create SFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098378/converting-bat-to-exe-with-no-additional-external-software-create-sfx?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: You can also just zip the file and send it to them. After they unzip it and store it somewhere, they can then run the batch file normally.

Comment: I'd be surprised if a .bat file was flagged as possibly harmful, but an .exe file not. Are you sure this is the solution to the problem?

Comment: I agree with hackoo, if you use a BAT to EXE converter most antivíruses will detect it as harmful I tried to convert .bat to .exe myself in the past and didn't have a good experience with it do to problems with antiviruses.

Comment: Just tell them to run the "Network Troiubleshooter" app in Windows 10. That will basically do the same things (and a few more). No need for a script at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you convert your batch file to exe most of antivirus doesn't like this and flag it as a malware or a trojan virus.

I recommend you to :

- zip your batch file without converting to exe and add a password and give them the code in their email, so in this case your zip file will not be flagged.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options here.

1. You can convert in to exe as described [in this link](https://superuser.com/questions/868340/how-can-i-convert-a-windows-batch-script-to-a-exe)
2. You can put all your files in a zip file and send it.
3. You can make a software using languages like python.
   I am asking about python because it is easy to understand.
   You can create a GUI code like this :

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(width = 500,height = 500)
canvas.pack()

def reset ():
    os.system('cmd /c "your lines of cmd code seperated by & operator"')

button = tk.Button(text= "RESET THE NETWORK CONFIGURATION" , command = reset)
canvas.create_window(200,200,window = button)

root.mainloop()
```

replace "your lines of cmd code seperated by & operator" , with you code .